# How to return integer value from notebook in adf pipeline

Tags: scala, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory, spark-notebook

I have a usecase where I need to return an integer as output from a synapse notebook in pipeline and pass this output in next stage of my pipeline.

Currently ***mssparkutils.notebook.exit()*** takes only string values. Is there any utility methods available for this?
I know we can cast the integer to string type and send it to the ***exit("")*** method. I wanted to know if I could achieve this without casting.

Answer (score 1):

`cast()`function is the standard and official method suggested by **Spark** itself. AFAIK, there is no other method. Otherwise, you need to manage it programmatically.

You can also try `@equals` in dynamic content to check whether the `exitValue` fetched from the notebook activity output equals to some specific value.

```
@equals(activity('Notebook').output.status.Output.result.exitValue, '<value>')
```

Refer: [Spark Cast String Type to Integer Type (int)](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-cast-string-type-to-integer-type-int/#:%7E:text=In%20Spark%20SQL%2C%20in%20order,selectExpr()%20and%20SQL%20expression.), [Transform data by running a Synapse notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/synapse-notebook-activity?tabs=classical#read-synapse-notebook-cell-output-value)

Answer (score 0):

instead, you can convert the string number to an integer in dynamic content. like this:

```
@equals(
    int(activity('Notebook').output.status.Output.result.exitValue)
    ,1)
```

or add an activity that sets the string value  to a variable that is an int.