# How to pass variable from Azure Synapse notebook to a copy data task in pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have a synapse notebook that makes a var:

```
  testvar = '6/26/2023'
```

I can run this from a pipeline in Azure but how do I pass the variable from the notebook to something else, like a copy data task? I know the following sql in the image below doesn't work, I'm just not sure what I need to do to pass this variable

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163025/how-to-return-integer-value-from-notebook-in-adf-pipeline this, maybe, will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass variable from Azure Synapse notebook Add exit value to the notebook using below code:

```
mssparkutils.notebook.exit(testvar)
```

[image]

Run Notebook activity in Synapse pipeline add set variable activity to the notebook activity. Create variable with below dynamic content.

```
@activity('Notebook1').output.status.Output.result.exitValue
```

[image]

Above variable will give the variable of notebook as output.

[image]

Pass the above variable value into the copy activity with below query.

```
SELECT * FROM data where date > '@{variables('testvar')}'
```

[image]

It will copy data from source to sink according to the query.
Data preview of above query:

[image]